# How can I move admin menu top-level items to submenu

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu, wp-admin

I'm using the code at https://markwilkinson.me/2014/11/altering-wordpress-admin-menus/ to change plugin-created top-level admin-menu items to submenu items of a 'misc' top-level item.

It works fine on those items which don't have their own submenu, but on items which have their own submenu the submenu disappears.

I don't know if the code can be appropriately modified, or if it can how to do it.

Comment: Add your code to check it

Comment: check page HTML source, may be the html is there but your theme style is preventing it.

Comment: @Mo'men Mohamed ... thanks. No code to add - using what's on that page, and simply swapping the slug of an item with a submenu for one without.

Comment: @ Alice... Thanks. It's not the css.

Comment: You cannot add a 3rd level of menus in WP admin.
See the answer to [How to Add a Third Level Sub Menu to the Wordpress Admin Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226990/how-to-add-a-third-level-sub-menu-to-the-wordpress-admin-menu) from wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ FluffyKitten... thanks. Ah, that explains it. So, those two-level space-hogging plugin-added menu items get to stay where they are... and if I ever need an additional level for stuff I create I'll use tab.

Comment: I'm going to add that as an answer just for completeness in case anyone else is asking the same question - even though it isn't your desired outcome, it looks like 'its not possible' is the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does not allow you to add a 3rd level of menus in WP admin.

See the answer to [How to Add a Third Level Sub Menu to the Wordpress Admin Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226990/how-to-add-a-third-level-sub-menu-to-the-wordpress-admin-menu) from wordpress.stackexchange.com

The answer from Karthikeyani explains why it currently isn't possible:

The definition of `add_submenu_page` requires the parent slug name. For example:

```
add_menu_page ( 'Test Menu', 'Test Menu', 'read', 'testmainmenu', '', '' );
add_submenu_page ( 'testmainmenu', 'Test Menu', 'Child1', 'read', 'child1', '');
```

The first parameter of the `add_submenu_page` is parent slug name $parent_slug. You may think you could use child1 ($menu_slug) as parent slug name to create the third level, but this does not work.

The parameters definition and source section in the [Wordpress developer documentation for add_submenu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) clearly states that you can only use the name of the *main menu of the plugin or the file name of the WordPress plugin* in parent slug name.

`add_submenu_page` Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/